# Duvida em relação ao switch case if

Tags: php

Isto esta certo ou errado? Só me funciona o `$estado=1;`:

```
<?php
// inicia sessão 
session_start();

// ligação à base de dados
include ('config.php');

// captura valores da compra
$estado = $_REQUEST['estado_compra'];
$id = $_REQUEST['id_compra'];
$acao = $_REQUEST['submit']; 
switch ($acao) {


case 'Alterar':
 if ($estado = 0) {
    $sql_alterar1 = "UPDATE compra_confirmada SET estado_compra = '$estado' WHERE id_compra = '$id'";
    $consulta1 = mysql_query($sql_alterar1); } 

 else  if ($estado = 1) {
      $sql_alterar2 = "UPDATE compra_confirmada SET estado_compra = '$estado'WHERE id_compra = '$id'";
      $consulta2 = mysql_query($sql_alterar2); }  

 else  if ($estado = 2 ) {
      $sql_alterar3 = "UPDATE compra_confirmada SET estado_compra = '$estado'WHERE id_compra = '$id'";
      $consulta3 = mysql_query($sql_alterar3); }  

    header("Location:".$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
    exit();
    break;
    }
?>
```

Comment: O correto não seria usar `==`? Por exemplo: `if( $estado == 0 )`

Comment: Algumas destas respostas lhe atenderam?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Mude seu código para:

```
// inicia sessão 
session_start();

// ligação à base de dados
include ('config.php');

// captura valores da compra
$estado = $_REQUEST['estado_compra'];
$id = $_REQUEST['id_compra'];
$acao = $_REQUEST['submit']; 

switch ($acao) {
    case 'Alterar':
        if ($estado == 0) {
            $sql_alterar1 = "UPDATE compra_confirmada SET estado_compra = '$estado' WHERE id_compra = '$id'";
            $consulta1 = mysql_query($sql_alterar1); 
        } 
        else  if ($estado == 1) {
            $sql_alterar2 = "UPDATE compra_confirmada SET estado_compra = '$estado'WHERE id_compra = '$id'";
            $consulta2 = mysql_query($sql_alterar2); 
        } 
        else  if ($estado == 2 ) {
            $sql_alterar3 = "UPDATE compra_confirmada SET estado_compra = '$estado'WHERE id_compra = '$id'";
            $consulta3 = mysql_query($sql_alterar3); 
        }  

    header("Location:".$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
    exit();
    break;
}
```

O operador `igual` do PHP é `==`. Você estava usando `$estado = 1`, o que tenta fazer atribuição de valor.

Leia mais sobre os operadores do PHP em:

http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.operators.comparison.php

Answer (score 1):

Utilize dois sinais de igual em comparações, da forma como fez estava realizando uma atribuição e isso é verdadeiro logo sempre entraria no `if`:

```
$estado == 1;
```

Desta forma esta comparando se os `valores` de ambos os lados do `==` são iguais.

Caso queira que a comparação seja mais fina utilize:

```
$estado === 1;
```

Desta forma esta comparando se os `valores` e o `tipo` de ambos os lados do `===` são idênticos.